# Very large Java ArrayList has slow traversal time

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, arraylist, linked-list

*Solution: My ArrayList was filled with duplicates. I modified my code to filter these out, which reduced running times to about 1 second.*

I am working on a algorithms project that requires me to look at large amounts of data.

My program has a potentially very large ArrayList (A) that has every element in it traversed. For each of these elements in (A), several other, calculated elements are added to another ArrayList (B). (B) will be much, much larger than (A).

Once my program has run through seven of these ArrayLists, the running time goes up to approximately 5 seconds. I'm trying to get that down to < 1 second, if possible.

I am open to different ways to traverse the ArrayList, as well as using a completely different data-structure. I don't care about the order of the values inside the lists, as long as I can go through all values, very fast. I have tried a linked-list and it was significantly slower.

Here is a snippet of code, to give you a better understanding. The code tries to find all single-digit permutations of a prime number.

```
public static Integer primeLoop(ArrayList current, int endVal, int size)
{        
    Integer compareVal = 0;
    Integer currentVal = 0;
    Integer tempVal = 0;
    int currentSize = current.size()-1;

    ArrayList next = new ArrayList();

    for(int k = 0; k <= currentSize; k++)
    {
        currentVal = Integer.parseInt(current.get(k).toString());
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {                                
            for(int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                compareVal = orderPrime(currentVal, endVal, i, j);
                //System.out.println(compareVal);

                if(!compareVal.equals(tempVal) && !currentVal.equals(compareVal))
                {     
                    tempVal = compareVal;
                    next.add(compareVal);

                    //System.out.println("Inserted: "+compareVal + "  with parent:  "+currentVal);

                    if(compareVal.equals(endVal))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Separation: " + size);
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    size++;
    //System.out.println(next);
    primeLoop(next, endVal, size); 
    return -1;
}
```

*Edit: Removed unnecessary code from snippet above. Created a currSize variable that stops the program from having to call the size of (current) every time. Still no difference. Here is an idea of how the ArrayList grows:
2,
29,
249,
2293,
20727,
190819,

Comment: *I don't care about the order of the values inside the lists, as long as I can go through all values, very fast.* Iterating every element should always be O(n). Iterating `m` lists should be O(mn).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe there are better strategies than the one you choose! Is it something from hackerrank or from project euler?

Comment: Did you try to use an embedded database?

Comment: If you can approximate the size of `next`, using [the `ArrayList` constructor with an initial capacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) will help you prevent growing arrays. This might save you some time, but perhaps won't drastically make it faster without improving the algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasKläger, I'm trying to find a chain of prime numbers that only change one digit at a time, and eventually becomes another, pre-determined prime number. I'm trying to implement it in a tree-like structure that searches breadth-first and returns the smallest amount of steps from the starting number, to the ending one. dejuth, It is only for 5 digit numbers, so I could put a cap on the ArrayList of 99999.

Comment: you can keep lists sorted. Then you can use binary search.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, not allowed for this assignment, otherwise I would.

Comment: Your `next` list grows too large, so it must contain duplicates. According to https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html there are only 9,592 primes up to 100_000!

Comment: @ThomasKläger Good call. I'll see if I can put in some logic tonight that reduces duplicates, then get back to you.

Comment: @ThomasKläger You were right, thank you. After carefully inspecting the list, I saw multiple duplicates that are easily removed. After fixing that and removing an unnecessary loop in another section of my code, I was able to get 1 second running times consistently. Is it possible to mark a comment as 'correct', since my problem is now solved? New to StackOverflow.

Comment: I've added my comment as an anwser too so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is an idea of how the ArrayList grows: 2, 29, 249, 2293, 20727, 190819

Your `next` list grows too large, so it must contain duplicates:

- 190_819 entries for 100_000 numbers?
- According to primes.utm.edu/howmany.html there are only 9,592 primes up to 100_000.

Getting rid of the duplicates will certainly improve your response times.

Answer (score 2):

When something is slow, the typical advice is to profile it. This is generally wise, as it's often difficult to determine what's the cause of slowness, even for performance experts. Sometimes it's possible to pick out code that's likely to be a performance problem, but this is hit-or-miss. There are some likely things in this code, but it's hard to say for sure, since we don't have the code for the `orderPrime()` and `primeLoop()` methods.

That said, there's one thing that caught my eye. This line:

```
    currentVal = Integer.parseInt(current.get(k).toString());
```

This gets an element from `current`, turns it into a string, parses it back to an `int`, and then boxes it into an `Integer`. Conversion to and from String is pretty expensive, and it allocates memory, so it puts pressure on garbage collection. Boxing primitive `int` values to `Integer` objects also allocates memory, contributing to GC pressure.

It's hard to say what the fix is, since you're using the raw type `ArrayList` for `current`. I surmise it might be `ArrayList<Integer>`, and if so, you could just replace this line with

```
    currentVal = (Integer)current.get(k);
```

You should be using generics in order to avoid the cast. (But that doesn't affect performance, just the readability and type-safety of the code.)

If `current` doesn't contain `Integer` values, then it should. Whatever it contains should be converted to `Integer` beforehand, instead of putting conversions inside a loop.

After fixing this, you are still left with boxing/unboxing overhead. If performance is still a problem, you'll have to switch from `ArrayList<Integer>` to `int[]` because Java collections cannot contain primitives. This is inconvenient, since you'll have to implement your own list-like structure that simulates a variable-length array of `int` (or find a third party library that does this).

But even all of the above might not be enough to make your program run fast enough. I don't know what your algorithm is doing, but it looks like it's doing linear searching. There are a variety of ways to speed up searching. But another commenter suggested binary search, and you said it wasn't allowed, so it's not clear what can be done here.

Comment: I will try your suggestion, as well as one suggestion above, and get back to you. I will try to minimize conversion. The values can be int, but as you say, ArrayList doesn't allow primitive types. The reason I don't believe binary search will work, is because I am never searching for anything. I am simply traversing. The order doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why you have this line

   current.iterator();

You don't use the iterator at all, you don't even have a variable for it. It's just waisting of time.

2. `for(int k = 0; k <= current.size()-1; k++)`

Instead of counting size every iteration, create value like:

```
int curSize = current.size() - 1;
```

And use it in loop.

It can save some time.

Comment: The 2016 Java way of iterating `Iterable current` would be `for (Object currentElement: current) <statement>`. The (lack of) speed most probably is due to something else.

Comment: Sure, i know 'bout foreach loops. Just mentioned some issues, that can be corrected in current code

Comment: The current.iterator() was leftover code. I've removed it from my question. I'll try the curSize idea soon and let you know, thanks!